# GCP Cross-region Private Service Connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp

We have an internal, regional LB in europe-west1 in `Project A`, and we have exposed it to `Project B` using Private Service Connect.

We established connectivity from a caller in `europe-west1`, so we know the connection works, but `Project B`'s resources are in europe-west3. Is there a way to allow cross-region connectivity for PSC?

We don't want to make the LB global for security reasons

This works:
[image: working in same region]

This doesn't
[image: Cross-region requests don't]

The error message from the GCP connectivity test is:

```
Packet could be dropped
The packet does not originate or is not directed to the same region as the regional load balancer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross Region Private Service Connect `is not possible` at the moment. But a feature request has been submitted to address the limitation. To stay updated on the status and progress of this feature request, please follow this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237990384) to access the feature request page. Once there, click on the `+1` and `star` buttons to receive notifications regarding any updates.